# Is there an explanation of Lucene BM25Similarity?

Tags: lucene, similarity

Is there a simple explanation? Am I suppose to understand it from the code [BM25Similarity Github](https://github.com/apache/lucene/blob/main/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/BM25Similarity.java)? If the answer is yes, what is the method called by IndexSearcher to score documents?

Is Lucene BM25Similarity implementation equal to the one in the literature?

I mean equal to the following:

tf / (k1 * (1 - b) + b * (dl / avdl) + tf)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is the implementation of BM25 from literature which can be found in [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okapi_BM25). Note that your provided formula is missing the IDF compunent. The parameters are set to k1 = 1.2 b = 0.75.

To get more insight on lucene's scoring mechanism you can always call the `explain()` function. More information on it can be found [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_5_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html).